# Will Window Phone 7 beep if it has messages

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd like to have my HTC HD7 Windows phone beep every 15 minutes if there are messages. Is that possible?

Comment: I do not see any such settings in my HTC HD7. Alternative is to Write our own App :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a couple of options.

You have access to the Vibrate mechanism like so:

```
VibrateController vibrate = VibrateController.Default; 
vibrate.Start(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
```

or you can play a sound:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; 
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;

Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("sounds/bonk.wav"); 
SoundEffect effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream); 
FrameworkDispatcher.Update(); 
effect.Play();
```

Doing either of these inside a Timer event would do what you're looking for.